# Send data from Kafka store to a topic/stream

Tags: apache-kafka

In Kafka Stream, is it possible that we keep storing data in Kafka store and once an event occurs, send a particular set of data to another topic/KStream?

Comment: Stores are built from topics. They don't emit events themselves because there's nothing to emit; it's already sent

Answer (score 0):

State stores uses RocksDB and changelog topic to store the internal data.  If you have a particular requirement of defining some business rule before processing the data, you can add the transformation or filtering and based on those result you can deliver data in subsequent Kafka streams/topic.

Also you can implement your custom processors.

This interactive queries article can also be helpful:

https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html

Comment: How can I send Kafka store data to a topic?

Comment: @manish As answered, the data is already in a changelog topic

Comment: @OneCricketeer i didnt get your point. can you please explain bit more?

Comment: @ManishKumar State stores are built from topics, as I commented above, there is nothing to "send" since the data is _already there_